# How to use AWS API Gateway Android SDK with Cognito Userpool Authorizer?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'm having trouble to properly use the integration of user pools with the API gateway from my Android app. (As per this documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html)

### The API Config

Authorizer for my user pool configured and the method configured to use the authorizer. Body mapping template:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
          "userid" : "$context.authorizer.claims.sub"
}
```

### The Android App

The following is only a collection of copy and paste snippets since it's scattered across different place in the app.

```
// init
credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
        context,
        IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
        IDENTITY_POOL_REGION);
userPool = new CognitoUserPool(
        context,
        USER_POOL_ID,
        CLIENT_ID,
        CLIENT_SECRET,
        new ClientConfiguration(),
        USER_POOL_REGION);

// login
user = aws.userPool.getUser(username);
user.getSessionInBackground(authHandler);
String token = session.getIdToken().getJWTToken();
Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<>();
logins.put(USER_POOL_ARN, token);
aws.credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);
aws.credentialsProvider.refresh();

// using the api
ApiClientFactory factory = new ApiClientFactory().credentialsProvider(
            aws.credentialsProvider);
apiClient = factory.build(MyAPIClient.class);
apiClient.mainGet()
```

### The current result

```
com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientException: {"message":"Unauthorized"}
                                                                 (Service: MyAPIClient; Status Code: 401; Error Code: null; Request ID: cefd713c-1234-1234-1234-b9e32fbdedb0)
                                                                    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientHandler.handleResponse(ApiClientHandler.java:294)
                                                                    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientHandler.invoke(ApiClientHandler.java:111)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:397)
                                                                    at $Proxy2.mainGet(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.my.mainGet(my.java:206)
```

So I can imagine that initializing the credentials provider with an identity pool will lead to a an identity token but I really need a token from the user pool. However that leads me to the question of how do I setup my ApiClient properly to use the user pool token?

Comment: Probably similar issue like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46345005/aws-api-gateway-authorizer-cognito-user-pool-not-working-message-unauthor  ?

Comment: have you tried logins.put("cognito-idp.<region>.amazonaws.com/<YOUR_USER_POOL_ID>", token); ? (see docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-integrating-user-pools-with-identity-pools.html)

Comment: @martin-schulze, did you finally solve it? How did you do it?

Comment: @Tobias unfortunately not. I actually gave up on that project.

Comment: @MartinSchulze Never give up!