# AWS API-Gateway Cognito Authorizer not working with a valid Token (nor access_token and id_token)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-cdk

I have a similar issue to this, but there are no solutions under that to my problem:

[AWS API-Gateway Cognito Authorizer not working with a valid Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55423096/aws-api-gateway-cognito-authorizer-not-working-with-a-valid-token)

I am using AWS CDK to deploy a project and I'm trying to use AWS Cognito User Pool to authorize my API Gateway.

The solution is there are different tokens in the response after authentication. In my situation the response are:

- id_token
- access_token

The solution was there to use `identity_token` instead of the access token. I was trying both, with and without Bearer, but it is not working still :'(

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what happened, but it was not working at all. I went to the user interface, clicked on the authorizer "edit" button, then just clicked save and it started to work :O Strange

Edit:
Don't forget to deploy it. So even if the solution worked before, I was wondering, why it is not working using Postman. After I deployed it, it works.